# UIView in iPhone rotation

Tags: iphone, rotation

My app looks like this:

UIViewController -> UIScrollView -> UIView

Everything works well when user is rotating device.

However, if user rotates device to vertical and then other view is added AFTER user rotated device, new view is still in Portrait mode!

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When addin the view, you have to manually adjust it's frame. Autoresizing only works when the view is part of a view hierarchy.

Comment: How can I adjust it's frame to preserve resizing rules set in InterfaceBuilder?

For example, if view should resize in height or stay the same